# What are acceptable abbreviations/shorthand for microcontroller?

Tags: discussion

We encounter several abbreviations and shorthand for microcontroller on the site:

- MCU
- Micro
- UC
- uC
- μC

By far the most common is **MCU** which I think is acceptable. Using **Micro** as long as the context is understood I think is also acceptable.

I take exception to the various forms using *mu* or 'u' as if it were a unit of something rather than a component. Especially **μC**, which might as well be a microcoulomb (even though it's generally obvious this is not the case from context).

When editing questions, I feel like changing instances of **UC**, **uC** and **μC** to **MCU**. [The Free Dictionary](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/Microcontroller) actually lists **μC** as an abbreviation for microcontroller, though I wish it wouldn't.

Is this agreeable or am I nit-picking?

Comment: **Mac users**, Option+M creates the µ symbol.

Comment: You're not *just* nit-picking. You're *wrong* if you change µC to MCU. If you want to change UC, fine, but it would be better to change it to µC than MCU because you know that was more likely the author's intent.

Answer (score 9):

**Nit-picking**. My belief is that you shouldn't edit someone's question like that unless the context is sorely needed anyway. And not everybody knows mcu means microcontroller anyway. (or micro controller unit technically)

Answer (score 6):

I use µC in the posts.  At the same time, I try to follow the convention an use the long form when the term is first encountered in the post: "... microcontroller (µC) ..." or "... µC (short for microcontroller) ... ".

In addition to saving ink, abbreviations (cutesy or not) stand out in the text and make rapid reading/scanning easier.

@JYelton  To answer your question, whether you're nit-picking or not.  You are.

Answer (score 4):

This is a international forum, so we need to be extra careful with abbreviations.  It's really not that much extra work to spell things out on occasion.  We see a lot of bad questions here where the asker assumes we know what his private abbreviation used in his lab or his corner of the world is supposed to mean.

I'd say in this instance that "MCU" and "micro" are OK *as long as it's clear from context*.  To be sure about that, spell out "microcontroller" at least once, then refer to it as "MCU" or "micro" afterwards.  Definitely don't put these abbreviations in a title, since there is no context for them.

For example a reasonable use of these abbreviations would in a question with the title *"Why is my microcontroller resetting a lot?"*.  In the text you can then say *"... the MCLR pin is floating, and when I fire up the Tesla coil the micro seems to go back to the start of the program ..."*.

As for trying to be cutesy with "µC" and the like, don't do that.  That's just another form of text-speak, which is annoying to read and is just begging for downvotes and excuses to close.

In general, the formost metric of good communication is clarity.  Also, when you come here to ask a question, you are basically asking lots of other people for a favor.  That goes a lot better when you show some respect.  Writing that saves you a few ms typing but is annoying to read is a bad idea.  Not only does this save a tiny cost for one at the expense of many, but it also says *I'm more important than you are*, which is not a smart thing to say to those you are seeking free help from.

Comment: I agree strongly with "the formost metric of good communication is clarity." However, I think you're unfairly categorizing some abbreviations as "text-speak" when I think it's more along the lines of trying to "learn the jargon" of the trade. I2C would be another example of a "cutesy" acronym, and I have heard pF (Pico Farads) pronounced "puff(s)".

Comment: And on the use of "µC" specifically, I can find published, peer-reviewed articles with that specific abbreviation in the title.

Comment: @W5VO: Just because some people perpetuate bad habits doesn't make them good habits. Yes, I've seen "uC" a few times too, but is it really worth annoying the readers and possibly leaving someone not so good with English wondering over a few small letters? The cost of a little more clarity is tiny, but the downside of not doing so is considerably larger.

Comment: Do you have evidence that the community considers this a bad habit, or is this a personal opinion?

Comment: Annoying the reader? Only if the reader is priggish  and pedantic. Says "I'm more important than you are"? Gee, I didn't know acronyms were extensions of egotism and snobbishness.

Answer (score 2):

Its fine as long as it conveys the right meaning and is not confusing. In this case \$ \mu C \$ means micro culombs and could be confusing so don't use it.

Abbreviations should be spelled out on the first use (probably not with more common ones like MCU) but there are a lot of acronyms used on this site that need to be looked up, in that case define what it is so people don't have to look it up.

There are a lot better things with your editing question time and much more serious mistakes to correct, so I wouldn't get too nit-picky and get around to the most serious mistakes first.

Answer (score -4):

I have to say that **μC** is the only abbreviation for microcontroller that I was familiar with. So no, please don't change **μC** to **MCU**. If you really feel you have to change **μC** to something else, please just spell it out - **microcontroller** isn't *that* long a word after all.